# Errors encountered

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

```
at training.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)

at training.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)

at training.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:15)
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

```
at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)

at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2149)

at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2130)

at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2110)


at training.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
... 2 more
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: add full exception in your question to better understand what's wrong

Comment: and also show the ` HibernateUtil` class code.

Comment: What's unclear about */hibernate.cfg.xml not found*?

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

Comment: <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
     org.postgresql.Driver
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
     postgres
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      PostG123
   </property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but session factory is not creating because of database connectivity,

So please add hibernate.cfg.xml file in the META_INF folder in your project.

```
1) add your Room class in the cfg file
2) add properties to connect the database like connection url, username, password and database driver class in your cfg file.
```

If META_INF folder is not in your project the put directly in src folder.

Try it.